# Connecting a port in linux from other machine

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, firewall, sockets

I'm going fast to asking this question so i'm apologize.

I'm on Linux Fedora 23.

I'm running an application [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) with listening a port using this argument.

```
-P 1337
```

That is fine and works good. I checked the connection by Telnet on the same OS (machine) and connection is perfect.

Now the problem is beginning.

I cant access that port using another machine.

I could telnet from another machine to Port 80 on that machine and have good connection with apache service. but i cant connect that (1337) port from another machine.

I even disabled all the following firewalls but nothing again.

```
firewallD
iptables
ip6tables
```

I even tried to connect that port from php on the same machine, And i surprised, Nothing again:

apache error_log file:

```
[Wed Feb 10 17:15:38.397896 2016] [:error] [pid 1171] [client 10.0.1.24:54434] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:1337 (Permission denied) in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 48
[Wed Feb 10 17:15:38.397987 2016] [:error] [pid 1171] [client 10.0.1.24:54434] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zyberspace\\Telegram\\Cli\\ClientException' with message 'Could not connect to socket "tcp://127.0.0.1:1337"' in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php:51\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/example.php(10): Zyberspace\\Telegram\\Cli\\RawClient->__construct('tcp://127.0.0.1...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 51
```

I even tried to connect them by Unix type connection:

```
unix:///etc/tg.sck
```

and nothing again

apache error_log file:

```
[Tue Feb 09 19:20:04.039823 2016] [:error] [pid 6124] [client 10.0.1.24:59958] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to unix:///tmp/tg.sck (No such file or directory) in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 48
[Tue Feb 09 19:20:04.039916 2016] [:error] [pid 6124] [client 10.0.1.24:59958] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zyberspace\\Telegram\\Cli\\ClientException' with message 'Could not connect to socket "unix:///tmp/tg.sck"' in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php:51\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/example.php(10): Zyberspace\\Telegram\\Cli\\RawClient->__construct('unix:///tmp/tg....')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 51
```

Comment: `netstat -pluton | grep 1337` shows it? and attached to IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: Returns: tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:1337 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 12041/bin/telegram- off (0.00/0/0)

Comment: It is attached to `127.0.0.1` (loopback interface), so nobody from outside can connect to it. Check the configuration to make it attach to `0.0.0.0` or to your IP address.

Comment: Dear @jcbermu Where should i config that? In linux or program source code?

Comment: It is part of the source code of Telegram-CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service *telegram* is running attached to `127.0.0.1`.

It is the loopback address of your system and it that can only be reached from the same device.

You need to modify the configuration of the service to make it attach to `0.0.0.0` or to your IP address.

Comment: I guess this is the true answer. Is that configurable or programmatically?

Comment: @Hammer i've checking the files on [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) but I couldn't found the file where it is configured. There should be somewhere a configuration file where you can define the interface it is attached to.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the Telegram-cli files and write the results here.

Comment: Thanks @jcbermu, by adding "--accept-any-tcp" flag to run command it would listen on all ip addresses. 

But the PHP on the same machine connection not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram-cli is definitely using 127.0.0.1 (or 0.0.0.0 with --accept-any-tcp switch) only as a bind address. I didn't find any configuration options to change this. However I can setup access from another computer to the telegram-cli on a specific inteface with the help of rinetd. It is very easy to configure and works like a charm. This way I solved this problem in a minute. You have to install rinitd to the host running telegram-cli (10.10.11.1 in my case) like

```
sudo apt-get install rinitd
```

The only thing to do is to edit /etc/rinitd.conf file The default content of this file looks like this:

```
#bindaddress bindport connectaddress connectport
192.168.1.145 80 192.168.1.254 8080
```

In my case I make it looks like this:

```
#bindaddress bindport connectaddress connectport
10.10.11.1 12345 127.0.0.1 12345
```

After that I'm able to connect to 10.10.11.1:12345 from another computer and get access to telegram-cli which listens on port 12345

Comment: Exposing ports on 127.0.0.0/8 is generally considered a security risk. Think twice, before you do it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm not exposing 127.0.0.1 to outside. What I'm doing is just forwarding traffic going to a specific port on 127.0.0.1 to another interface, accessible from outside. That's it.